# Не запускается простейший сервлет - ошибка HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, tomcat

Господа, в чем может быть проблема, если даже простой сервлет на Tomcat не запускается?

Запускаю на Win7 x64, tomcat-8.0.9, jdk1.7.0_51

Код сервлета HelloServlet.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Hello World!</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Содержимое файла web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5">

    <display-name>MyFirstProject</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <display-name>HelloServletdisplay</display-name>
        <servlet-name>HelloServletname</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServletname</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloServlettest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Ошибка:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /MyFirstProject/HelloServlettest    
type Status report
message /MyFirstProject/HelloServlettest
description The requested resource is not available.
```

Структура папок:

```
apache-tomcat-8.0.9
|
+--- webapps
|    |
|    +--- MyFirstProject
|    |    |
|    |    +--- WEB_INF
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    +--- classes
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    + HelloServlet.class
|    |    |    |    + HelloServlet.java
|    |    |    |    
|    |    |    + web.xml
```

Comment: @hELL63, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @hELL63, как вы деплоите приложение на сервер? Вы уверены, что оно деплоится в контекст /MyFirstProject? В менеджере Томката ваше приложение отображается? Посмотрите логи Томката, возможно, там будет полезная информация.

Comment: > как вы деплоите приложение на сервер? Вы уверены, что оно деплоится в контекст /MyFirstProject?

Запускаю Томкат и перехожу по ссылке http://localhost:81/MyFirstProject/HelloServlettest. Получаю ошибку 404. (Ответил как понял ваш вопрос)
Деплоить - это делать что-то с .war-файлом?

В менеджере Томката приложение отображается. Параметр Running в таблице стоит true.

Какие именно файлы логов смотреть?
Выложил все: http://pastebin.com/uueyaznw

Comment: Попробовал собрать ваш проект - получил ошибку. Метод `doGet` класса `HttpServlet` имеет сигнатуру

>void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, __HttpServletResponse__ response) throws ServletException, IOException`,

а у вас

>void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, __ServletResponse__ response) throws ServletException, IOException`

Как вы это вообще собрали? Попробуйте для самоконтроля добавлять аннотацию `@Override` ко всем методам, которые переопределяете.

Comment: Все исправил, получил новую ошибку:

HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

type Status report
message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.